# Conda command not found after installing anaconda3

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

After installing Anaconda correctly. l wanted after finishing the installation to do the following. l forget to do it while installing anaconda:

```
export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin"
conda --version
conda command not found
```

then l opened

```
gedit /root/.bashrc
```

l added  at the end of file

```
export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin"
```

but l still get

```
conda --version
conda command not found
```

**EDIT1:  gedit /root/.bashrc**

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin"
```

l did also the following :

```
 echo $PATH

/home/ahmed/anaconda3/bin:/home/ahmed/anaconda3/bin:/home/ahmed/anaconda3/bin:/home/ahmed/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

What's wrong with my code  ? there are lots path in this path  !!

Comment: You may need to run: "source ~/.bashrc"

Comment: Also can you share what's in your .bashrc file?

Comment: Okey, please see my update

Comment: If you type `bash` (it will spawn a new bash) and run `conda` again does it work? Or do what @ally-e suggested.

Comment: source ~/.bashrc worked correctly then bash
Command 'bash' is available in '/bin/bash'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
bash: command not found

Comment: I would delete the line you put in your .bashrc and instead add _export PATH="~/ahmed/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"_

Comment: Ok , i did it by it still doesn't work

Comment: Check my edit please and perhaps try again?

Comment: gedit .bashrc
Command 'gedit' is available in '/usr/bin/gedit'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
gedit: command not found

Comment: Perhaps use vi or nano to edit your .bashrc

Comment: You have this on your PATH multiple times. You should try removing it and putting it in just once.

Answer (score 4):

You said that you are adding this to your `PATH: PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin"` . But when you shared your `.bashrc`, Anaconda appears to be installed here: `/home/ahmed/anaconda3`.

If you have multiple installs, delete them. I would suggest that you uninstall, reinstall once to your desired location (`/home/ahmed/anaconda3` is most likely preferred to installing into root). You should download the installer from here: https://www.continuum.io/downloads. The installer will provide you with an option to add Anaconda to your PATH automatically, select that option. Restart your terminal and try to run:

```
conda info
```